# How to personalize Yammer embed box

Tags: yammer

I would like people in our company to be able to embed various yammer feeds into their sharepoint sites. However, the default embed box isn't looking great (the top of the box is basically name of the feed in arial on Yammer-blue background). Is there a way how to improve its look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yammer doesn't allow you to customize the look & feel of their embed feed.  But you can turn off the header via configuration option.

Also that blue background is coming from your network configuration.  The same color as your web version, and you can change it inside Network configuration page.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the "share something with this group..." box where you can enter something to be posted on Yammer from the feed? I'd like to hide that and only display things that have been posted, but I haven't found any documentation on how to do that. Or at the very least, I'd like to make it smaller. It's currently about 65px high, I'd prefer to have it no more than 30px if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Yammer offers an embed preview editor that allows you to get rid of the header and footer, among other things, and preview it online: https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

You can remove the blue header by adding a config line in the embed code:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
         container: "#divname",
         network: "yourdomain.ca",
         feedType: "group",
         feedId: "all",
         config: {
                 header: false,
                 footer:false,
                 hideNetworkName:false
             }
          });
```

The widget will fill whatever div you've placed it in, so you can make it as tall or as wide as you like. Simply modify the div with css or an inline style:

```
    <div id="divname" style="height:600px; width:80%;"></div>
```

To my knowledge you cannot get rid of the input box at the very top, but you can customize what it says.